# SwiftUI & Redux : how to perform an action on a view when some data changes outside of its scope?

Tags: redux, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI with Redux and I would like to add a little animation when the displayed view is updated, i.e. the app starts with a loading view, then after loading data with my API it's replaced with the main view, and during this replacement I want to animate a black view appearing and disappearing.

This is how I would do it if I could simply do it on a local scope :

```
struct AppView: View {
    @State private var loaded = false
    @State private var isSwitchingView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if loaded {
                MainView()
            } else {
                LoadingView()
            }
            Color.black
                .opacity(isSwitchingView ? 1 : 0)
            }                
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                // load() is an async function returning true if data is loaded correctly
                let loadedResult = await load()
                if loadedResult != loaded {
                    updateView(loadedResult: loadedResult)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateView(loadedResult: Bool) {
        withAnimation(
            .linear(duration: 0.25)
        ) {
            isSwitchingView = true
        }
        delay(0.25) {
            loaded = loadedResult
            withAnimation(
                .linear(duration: 0.25)
            ) {
                isSwitchingView = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that since I'm using redux, I'm loading data and updating the expected displayed view outside of `AppView`.

This is what my AppView actually looks like with redux :

```
struct AppView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store<AppState>
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch store.state.currentView {
            case .loading:
                AppLoadingView()
            case .main:
                MainView()
            }
            // how to animate this Color.black in that situation (when store.state.currentView changes)?
            Color.black
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by using `.onChange(of: store.state.currentView)`